# get the higher value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with ruby on rails and i have a question.

I have a table who contains data like this:

```
{id: 471, from_city_id: '9', to_city_id: 14, product_id: 61, saving_in_from_currency: 262.0},
{id: 472, from_city_id: '9', to_city_id: 14, product_id: 61, saving_in_from_currency: 150.0}
```

Here the data model,

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: pricings
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  from_city_id            :integer
#  to_city_id              :integer
#  product_id              :integer
#  saving_in_from_currency :decimal(, )
#  created_at              :datetime
#  updated_at              :datetime
#

class Pricing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_city, :class_name => 'City'
  belongs_to :to_city, :class_name => 'City'
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I try to display a table in my view like this:

for example:

the user select the from_city_id, and i display for this id all the elements like this

```
            to_city_id        to_city_id          to_city_id
product_id    price               price               price
product_id    price               price               price   
product_id    price               price               price
product_id    price               price               price
```

For the moment i select the "saving_in_from_currency", by the from_city_id, the to_city_id and product_id.

But like you can see, in some case, only the id and the saving_in_from_currency change , and i want to display for each case like this the higher value, here "262.0".

Do you have any idea of how i could do this?(and sorry for my english)

Thank you.

Comment: sorry but you need to explain more, what are we trying to do ? a form ? a view?

Comment: I add this immediatly in the post. thank you for the remark.

Comment: how are you getting this json? from a controller or api ?

Comment: No i write it in json to be more easy to read, but i use the data in my table, everything is in my database

Comment: you want these two records to show only one time in the table right? with the higher value 262.

Comment: I add it but yes i want to show only the one with the higher value,

Comment: I think the answer below does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you'd likely benefit from using `distinct` in your query.  I suspect something like this would accomplish what you desire.  (Replace the model name of course, as it wasn't mentioned above).

```
Model.select(:from_city_id, :to_city_id, :product_id).distinct.order(saving_in_from_currency: :desc)
```

Edit:
Or, if you need access to attributes on the model other than `from_city_id`, `to_city_id`, `product_id`, this would also work.

```
# Replace with any additional constraints as needed
p = Pricing.all.order(saving_in_from_currency: :desc)
p.uniq! { |a| [a.from_city_id, a.to_city_id, a.product_id] }
```

Comment: thank you, i am new with rails, and i have a question(maybe stupid question), but you do this in the view or controller?

Comment: It would be best to perform these within the controller.  While it can technically be done in the view, it's conventionally frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your answers, i will try it after. i Will let you know if this work and accept your answer